# GEt Steam or CSGO backpack/inventory using steam API

Tags: steam-web-api, steambot

Is this possible to get **Steam**(753) or **CsGo**(730) full backpack/inventory using steam API?

I found an API where I get the full backpack/inventory of **Dota2**(570) **TF2**(440)

Here is the API :

**URL** : http://api.steampowered.com/IEconItems_/GetSchema/v0001/?key={api_key}

When I put steam or csgo appid , this API return 'NOT FOUND'. Further , I search for many API regarding this but not found any which should help me to get all the items.

I found many API regarding this which should give me the CSGO backpack of a particular user.

Here is the one API.

**URL** : http://api.steampowered.com/IEconItems_730/GetPlayerItems/v0001/?key={api_key}&SteamID={steam_id64}

From this api I can get any steam user's backpack except steam (753).I also searched many APi regarding this , but the result is same.

I know that there are no official api to get CSGO items but then where from many websites show full csgo backpack on there website for trade and bet.

If anyone know how to get this please reply to my question.

Comment: duplicate question, check this for finding the answer you are looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25977803/steam-web-api-getting-csgo-inventory/26011027#26011027

Answer (score 2):

You can construct the API URL using this statement:

```
string.Format("http://steamcommunity.com/profiles/{0}/inventory/json/{1}/{2}/", steamid.ConvertToUInt64(), appid, contextId)
```

However, if you're using [SteamBot](https://github.com/Jessecar96/SteamBot/), there's no need to do this manually.  The [`GenericInventory` class](https://github.com/Jessecar96/SteamBot/blob/master/SteamTrade/GenericInventory.cs) handles making and parsing the request for you automatically.

Comment: Yes you are right.According to the link we get the players inventory.And not the full descriptions..Only little bit info.From this link we get 'defindex' which we can compare with the total steam item inventory and get full details like image,full name etc .

But if I don't get the full steam inventory then how can I compare all items?

And I am using php/mysql. its not an issue if I get all api correctly.

Thanks for your cooperation .

Answer (score 0):

After an extensive search, I've come across a noteworthy discovery: Steam appears to be actively obstructing a considerable number of API requests, particularly those related to inventories, profiles, items, and various other data. In response to this, several alternative services have been developed, such as [www.steamwebapi.com](http://www.steamwebapi.com), steamapis, steamworks, and numerous others. These platforms allow you to directly utilize their endpoints without encountering blocking issues, and they should encompass all the information you're seeking. I believe this information could prove to be quite beneficial.