# Steam web API getting CS:GO inventory

Tags: json, steam, steam-web-api

Alright, so I have been looking for this all over the internet, and what I have found out is that when you want to get someones steam inventory you use this:

```
http://api.steampowered.com/IEconItems_{appid}/GetPlayerItems/v0001/?key={apikey}&steamid={steamid}&format=json
```

But the problem is that when I do that for CS:GO (appid: `730`), I just get an empty response back, even though the user has items in their inventory.

Comment: sounds like a bug then, might want to contact steam?

Comment: Kinda also what i thought, but wasn't sure if it was me doing it wrong

Comment: But then again, if i go to here and sign in, they can read my inventory http://csgolounge.com/match?m=1483

Comment: possibly related? https://github.com/Jessecar96/SteamBot/issues/508

Answer (score 16, accepted):

if you want to get the json just use one of the following links:

general steam inventory: ( 1: games, 3: coupons, 6: trading cards, 7: rewards )

```
http://steamcommunity.com/id/<USERURL>/inventory/json/753/1
http://steamcommunity.com/profiles/<STEAMID>/inventory/json/753/1

http://steamcommunity.com/id/<USERURL>/inventory/json/753/3
http://steamcommunity.com/profiles/<STEAMID>/inventory/json/753/3

http://steamcommunity.com/id/<USERURL>/inventory/json/753/6
http://steamcommunity.com/profiles/<STEAMID>/inventory/json/753/6

http://steamcommunity.com/id/<USERURL>/inventory/json/753/7
http://steamcommunity.com/profiles/<STEAMID>/inventory/json/753/7
```

games :

```
http://steamcommunity.com/id/<USERURL>/inventory/json/<APPID>/2
http://steamcommunity.com/profiles/<STEAMID>/inventory/json/<APPID>/2
```

the problem was not the counter-strike appid, 
you just used an old link that only works for the general steam inventory.
I suggest you using the link using STEAMID because not every steamuser has set a customurl.

Comment: does it block after the call limit of 20 per minute?

Comment: So if i have a traffic of over 10000 per second on my website, I am basically screwed?

Comment: if youre website does this many calls you are screwed anyway... you should strongly consider your concept and think about caching if possible

Comment: Do we have any third party plugin Shiv can do this? I think Bitskins have this kind of functionality in which you can choose whether to display your inventory from steam or from cache. I wonder how did they do that...

Comment: yes but the one most websites use costs some money... http://csgo.steamlytics.xyz/api see they have different plans for different website "sizes" - there might be different ones but most websites use this one afaik